# Re-rendering a DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, flex4

I have a datagrid within a custom component. This DG accepts a nested object as its dataprovider, and so my datagrid is rendered like this :

```
<mx:DataGrid id="privilegesDG" dataProvider="{privArray}" width="100%" variableRowHeight="true">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Name" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Alias" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Roles Assigned" dataField="roles">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:VBox creationComplete="box1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
                            <fx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    import com.pm.modules.events.UpdateDBEvent;

                                    import mx.containers.HBox;
                                    import mx.controls.Label;
                                    import mx.controls.LinkButton;
                                    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                                    [Bindable]private var prID:int;
                                    protected function box1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                    {
                                        for each(var temp:Object in data.roles){
                                            prID = temp.rid;
                                            var hgrp:HBox = new HBox();
                                            hgrp.autoLayout = false;

                                            var lbl:Label = new Label();
                                            lbl.text = temp.rname;

                                            var lb:LinkButton = new LinkButton();
                                            lb.label = 'X';
                                            lb.focusEnabled = true;
                                            lb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick);

                                            hgrp.addElement(lbl);
                                            hgrp.addElement(lb);

                                            this.addElement(hgrp);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
                                        dispatchEvent(new UpdateDBEvent(UpdateDBEvent.ON_DELETE_PRIVILEGE_ROLE_MAP,0,0,0,prID,0,true));
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </fx:Script>
                        </mx:VBox>
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

So i have an inline itemrenderer that displays the nested data. Now eveytime an update operation occurs, i call a function to re-populate this datagrid. But the column which gets populated with the nested data dsnt display anything...

I searched the net and found that mayb i shld call the updateDisplayList function for this component ?

So i tried smthing like this :

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
        }


        protected function handleResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
            if(event.result.toString() == 'false')
                Alert.show("Could not perform operation");
            else{
                RO.getPrivilegesAndRoles(); //re-populates DG
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }
```

I really dont know what I shld put inside that function. Should i call the re-populating function inside updateDisplayList. I tried that but it dsnt work ...

Answer (score 2):

The `creationComplete` event of your item renderer occurs only one time on initialization. As far as item renderers are recycling the new data won't populate in your item renderer.

You can solve it two ways:

1. Create MXML item renderer. As far as its base class is `VBox` it is the best option here. So you can get rid of data binding to populate data changes automatically. To populate all the roles use `Repeater` component instead of your loop using `{data.roles}` as data provider.
2. The second option is to use ActionScript and to have `UIComponent` as the base class. In this case you should override `override public function set data(value:Object):void` and call `invalidateDisplayList()` from there as far as subscribing on `data.roles`'s `collectionChange` event and call `invalidateDisplayList()` from change handler too. Then in `updateDisplayList()` you should loop your data and create/populate all the controls. The second option can give you better performance but it is not a good way for novices.

So I recommend you to use MXML version with binding.

Comment: the reason i cannot use Repeater is because the data.roles is an array of arrays and it has dynamic indices ... i.e the number of roles varies.. data[roles][0] =>array(),data[roles][1]=>array() .. there may be 0 or n number of roles.. i have to use the for loop to access this array.. can u elaborate on your 2nd option ? i am a novice but maybe u can show me some code sample .. ?Any help wld be appreciated .. :)